# Дерево дуб / дерево-дуб

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать? Я считаю, что без дефиса надо, так как дуб – это вид дерева. Может, однако, также и-с от мною придаваемого значения это зависит-таки?

`1. В дупле какого-то дерева дуба я нашёл – сундук!`

`2. В дупле какого-то дерева дуба я нашёл – сундук!`

Comment: Нет, дуб - это и дерево-дуб, и древесина-дуб, и тупой кто-то - дуб. Но по-умолчанию дуб есть дерево, говорить на дереве дубе - это излишество, на дубе достаточно. Если же это родовое слово, то родовое слово не склоняется - "В дупле дерева дуб". Через дефис пишутся всякие сказочные сущности Дерево-дуб, Мальчик-с-пальчик, Соловей-разбойник, сон-трава, дурман-трава - тогда можно склонять обе части. Правда я не совсем уверен насчет того, как Дерево-дуб будет существовать, хотя может это типа Энт и дуб в одном лице. То есть дерево и дуб - это какая-то тавтология как ни крути.

Comment: Жар-птица, Сорока-воровка - дефисное написание не связано с родовыми словами. Терминология и таксономия - это вообще не из этой оперы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. О сочетании **дерево дуб****

**[§ 122](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp122.php)**

Следующие сочетания пишутся **раздельно**.

1. Сочетания с приложениями, следующими за определяемым словом, если первое слово является по значению более широким и общим, а второе — более узким и конкретным. Сюда относятся следующие случаи:

а) два нарицательных существительных, выражающих **родовое и видовое** понятия в классификации природных объектов, напр.: птица иволга, рыба треска, ***дерево ольха,*** цветок роза, минерал лазурит, металл литий;

Примечание. Следует отличать такие сочетания от сочетаний типа *птица-носорог, рыба-попугай,* пишущихся через дефис (см. выше § 120, п. 1 б); в этих случаях названием птицы и рыбы являются сочетания целиком (поскольку носорог — не птица, а попугай — не рыба).

Итак, ***дерево дуб*** пишется только раздельно. **Дефис** возможен при перестановке,  сравнить: трава полынь и  [полынь-трава](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/66625/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%8C).

**2. Решение задачи**

*В дупле какого-то **дерева дуба** я нашёл – сундук!*

Корректно: *В дупле какого-то **дерева, возможно дуба**, я нашёл – сундук!*

В дупле ***дерева дуба*** я нашёл – сундук! Но здесь необоснованное употребление родового понятия "дерево".

**3. А когда же возможны** такие сочетания: ***дерево дуб и дуб-дерево?***

В описаниях деревьев требуется **сравнение,** например: ***Дерево березу** нужно отличать от кустарника  с таким же названием.* Это [карликовая береза](https://7dach.ru/LenaMedvednikova/bereza-karlikovaya-puteshestvie-iz-tundry-v-sad-152722.html) (ёрник), которая растет в высокогорных районах.

Дефисное написание возможно в **поэтических текстах:**

*Ах ***полынь-трава*** горько-сладкая, Ты любовь моя Богом данная.*

*В поле **дуб-дерево** стоит. Я бы назвал его отцом. Но он не скажет мне «Иди ко мне, сынок».*  (Текст немного изменен).

Comment: А почему ответ не принят? Вроде подробный и есть всë, что надо. Даже я узнал что-то новое.

Comment: Я просто ещё не успел.